# React navigation - hide ui from primary stack when navigating to nested stack

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

How can I hide the UI in my primary stack when I navigate to my nested drawer stack?

Currently, the header from my primary stack, shows above the header in my nested stack when I navigate to a screen using:

```
navigation.navigate('Drawer', {screen: 'About'});
```

Navigator:

```
function DrawerStack() {
    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Video Episodes" component={VideoEpisodesScreen} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Test Yourself" component={TestYourselfScreen} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="My Results" component={MyResultsScreen} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="About" component={AboutScreen} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Tests" component={TestsScreen} />
            <Drawer.Screen
                name="Bookmarked Videos"
                component={BookmarkedVideosScreen}
            />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
}

export default function AppNavigator() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="Home"
                    component={HomeScreen}
                    options={stackOptions}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="Drawer"
                    component={DrawerStack}
                    options={drawerOptions}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="MyResultsScreen"
                    component={MyResultsScreen}
                    options={options}
                />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the stack navigation header by setting the option `headerShown` to false. I'm not sure how `drawerOptions` is configured but I think you could do something like this in yout `<Stack.Navigator>`

```
<Stack.Screen
    name="Drawer"
    component={DrawerStack}
    options={{...drawerOptions, headerShown: false}}
/>
```

Comment: How can I get the `navigation` prop in AppNavigator? So I can determine wether or not to show or hide the header.

Comment: In `options`, you can assign it like this `<Stack.Screen options={({navigation}) => { return {...your navigation options}} />` but it will be navigation of StackNavigator. I guess you want to know the page of its child (which is drawer). In this case, you may set vary the headerShown based on navigation params and assigned in drawer navigation if it needs to show the header or not (in drawer navigation, you can get stack navigation by https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#dangerouslygetparent)